# check if any of the characters from an array exists in a string

Tags: php, character

I want to check if any of the characters from `$array` exists in `$string`:

```
$array = array('â','à','á','ê','ô');
$string = 'hello every body';
```

Comment: `if (strspn($string, implode($array)) > 0)`

Comment: @Mark Baker, I think that will only work if the string starts with one of the chars in $array

Comment: indeed, the docs seem to say "Finds the length of the initial segment of subject that contains only characters from mask."

Comment: It certainly sounds ambiguous documentation

Comment: Easier approach might be `if (strlen($string) !== strlen(str_replace($array, '', $string)))` anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$found = false;
foreach ($array as $char){
    //you can use strpos [without 'i'] for case-sensitive comparison
    if (stripos($char,$string) !== false){ 
        $found=true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you  very much! i also think that , but my $array very long so  I think it is not optimal.

Comment: yes, not very efficient. you could try Mark Baker's str_replace method. or maybe, you could invert your array, eg if not everything is ASCII then something is 'special'